# Particle system in ARCore

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, particle-system

Has ARCore a particle system (without using Unity)?

I'm already using `ViroCoreAR` but now, I want to use ARCore but I don't know if ARCore has a particle system just like `ViroCoreAR` or even ARKit for (iOS).

Answer (score 1):

ARCore doesn't have a particle system.
A particle system is a graphic feature that may be in the game engine you're using, it isn't related in any way to what ArCore is set to do.

Comment: I'm new at AR develop, but I know that ARKit has something called emitter node which renders particle sprites and configure the direction, the velocity, number of particles to emmit and other things. My question is... Has ARCore something like that?

Comment: No. but you can use a game engine (Unity, Cocos2d-x, other) that has this feature.
What are you using for your OpenGL Rendering?

Comment: As I told you, I'm actually using ViroCore, is a platform that doesn't require to know OpenGL, it allows to you render objects, (I don't know what render engine it uses), but I have been considering change to ARCore, in Android you can use a SDK, Sceneform, which helps to render 3d content so... I don't know if that is what you refer...

Comment: You engine has particle system feature:
https://virocore.viromedia.com/docs/particle-effects
You can use it, they claim they support ArCore so they are using ArCore.

Answer (score 1):

There's no official Google's particle engine at the moment (early March 2019). But you can use easily-configurable particle system library like [Confetti](https://github.com/jinatonic/confetti) by Jinyan Cao.

The simplest `ConfettoGenerator` might look like this:

```
final List<Bitmap> allPossibleConfetti = constructBitmapsForConfetti();
Utils.generateConfettiBitmaps(new int[] { Color.BLACK }, 20);
final int numConfetti = allPossibleConfetti.size();

final ConfettoGenerator confettoGenerator = new ConfettoGenerator() {
    @Override
    public Confetto generateConfetto(Random random) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = allPossibleConfetti.get(random.nextInt(numConfetti));
        return new BitmapConfetto(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Has anything changed since March 2019? (It's now March 2021) It doesn't look like Google has made any progress in this direction.

Comment: That confetti library is not specific to AR Core

Comment: Nothing changed since March 2019. Google is Google )) And yes, `Confetti` library is not specific to ARCore.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It's upsetting that Apple gives their devs so much more love

Comment: Three Apple's frameworks – SceneKit, Metal and SpriteKit – generate particles. Wait for such an ability inside fourth one – RealityKit module (I suppose this year).